# Message Box won't show, and no errors are found. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

I'm trying to make my application do something when two selections from two different List Boxes match. To test I put in "MessageBox.Show("It works!!!"), and although I get no syntax errors logically it's not working properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Distance_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputListBox.SelectedIndex == 0 && outputListBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("It works!!!");       

        }


    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've made sure all the names are correct, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: The desired action is for it to display a box showing that when the two inputs (from the listboxes are selected) the box will show up demonstrating it works. I'm very new to C#, and while I know how to place them I have no idea what to do with them. I think I "wired" it up write. The way my book taught me was to double click the button, and then write the code which is where "private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" comes from.

Comment: [This is what I got.](https://i.imgur.com/DNxPv3r.png) Not exactly sure what I'm looking at though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code looks good, so it must be that something is not hooked up correctly. The two posible issues I can think of are:

- Your button is not hooked up to your event handler. Ensure the method is actually being executed when the button is pressed.
- The index values you are checking for may not be what you expect them to be.

I would do the following to help determine the issue:

1. Comment out the if statement and see if the message is displayed.

If it is not, your button is not hooked up to your method. If it is, there is something wrong with the conditions in the if statement.

I would give code examples but I am on mobile. I hope this helped!

Comment: I think it isn't hooked up properly as people are saying. I commented out that if statement, and still no dice. I thought that double clicking the button, and inputting my code would work, but apparently not. Now what?

Comment: Try double clicking the button again and see if it takes you to the same place. If it doesn't, then you know your code is in the wrong spot. If it does, yet your code is still not being run, you will need to debug your code by placing a break point at the top of your method.

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio, this may be a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx. If you find it difficult to follow, you may rather watch a YouTube video on the subject instead.

Comment: Just a problem from my text book lol. I like VS, but getting used to working with the designer is a bit weird to me.